# Power BI & Excel query - Taking values from adjacent column along a row element

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi

[Table][Food Choice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJPBm.png)

I want to take the values from the column and insert on the choice. Can anyone suggest how can this be done in excel and power BI.

E.G this is how this should look like.

[Food Choice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29QiO.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data instead of images. Here is a tool to create ASCII tables for sites just like this one. [link](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, a "nested if" isn't elegant but it will work for your case.  Assuming Menu is in the B column, Toffee is in the D column, Coffee is in the E column, and Chinese is in the F column here is the formula for your Choice column starting on row 2.

```
=IF(B2="Toffee",D2,IF(B2="Coffee",E2,IF(B2="Chinese",F2,"Not Found")))
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. Do you know the equivalent in PowerBI?

Comment: You can do it n Power Query Editor with a Conditional Column like this:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Choice", each if [Menu] = "Toffee" then [Toffee] else if [Menu] = "Coffee" then [Coffee] else if [Menu] = "Chinese" then [Chinese] else "None Found")`


Replace #"Changed Type1" with the previous step in your Power BI workbook.